# URL giving timeout on application but working fine on safari in iOS device

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I am trying to get response from one URL in my iOS app which is giving me timeout but when i open that URL on safari, it seems work fine.

I tried installing the certificate as well from the URL but it still not working.

Can any one let me know what could be the issue?

NSMutableURLRequest *urlReq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                          timeoutInterval:180.0];

```
NSString * httpMeth = HttpMethod;
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:httpMeth];

__block void (^completionHandler)(NSData*, NSURLResponse*, NSError*) =
^void(NSData *data ,NSURLResponse *response ,NSError *connectionError)
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self connectionRecivedResponse:response withData:data
                        connectionError:connectionError];
    });

};

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
```

[[session dataTaskWithRequest:urlReq
                completionHandler:config]

Comment: Did you setup App Transport Security Settings in the .plist file?
Have you some other issues in the console?

Comment: I am getting timeout error in console.
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."

Comment: Possible duplicate of: 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086812/code-1001-the-request-timed-out) & [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972822/error-error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1001-the-request-timed-out) & [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216484/error-error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1001-the-request-timed-out)

Comment: None of these links resolving the issue. I am using NSURLConnection.

Comment: Can you give some test link to your server?

Comment: No, i can't share that.

Comment: Sorry dude, I have tried. Without any test and additional info I can not help.

Comment: Share your code when you create your urlConnection

Comment: Added in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159068/discussion-between-mini2008-and-biloshkurskyi-ss).